# Function to remove self loops but preserve multiple edges in Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The function `SimpleGraph[]` removes both self-loops and multiple edges in the same vertices of a Graph. Is there a function that removes self-loops only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
g = AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 3, 1}, {3, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]
adj = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
Do[adj[[i, i]] = 0, {i, 1, Length[adj]}];
AdjacencyGraph[adj]
```

[image]

Comment: An alternative to the `Do` loop would be `adj = ReplacePart[AdjacencyMatrix[g], {i_, i_} :> 0]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`IGSimpleGraph`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igsimplegraph) from my IGraph/M package.

`IGSimpleGraph[g, MultiEdges -> True]` keeps multi-edges.

Comment: Awesome package! I didn't know about it. However, I couldn't install it. I get: `The paclet IGraphM was successfully installed, but it will not be available in this session because it is not compatible with the currently running version of the Wolfram system.` I run Mathemaica 12.3.1.0 in MacOSX (ARM architecture).

Comment: @stathisk The next version with support macOS on ARM. To use the current version, you need to run the Intel version of Mathematica.

Answer (score 7):

```
removeSelfLoops = EdgeDelete[#, (UndirectedEdge | DirectedEdge)[a_, a_, ___]] &;
```

**Example:**

```
g = Graph[{"A" <-> "B", "A" <-> "B", "A" <-> "C", "B" <-> "C", 
    "C" <-> "C"}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400];

Row[{g, removeSelfLoops @ g}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]